# Options for re-plumbing a new vanity install with a vent in the way

Tags: plumbing, vent

I would like to install a new vanity. It is designed to go flat against the wall, and has some open space at the lower end part:

[image: Vanity - back side dimensions]

Current plumbing was made all "unique" and gets in the way:

[image: Unique plumbing]

As I later discovered this was due to a stale-air vent going through the middle of the wall. Orange tape marks the vent location:

[image: Sink removed - orange tape shows vent duct location]

Moving the vent is out of the project scope.

I thought I can cut into the drain via WYE fitting underneath the old setup as [described here](https://www.finehomebuilding.com/2018/03/01/help-tying-drain-line), but I still can't avoid hitting the vent duct.

Does it sound like a good plan to attempt to bend the vent a bit to provide enough space for 1 1/2 ABS pipe?

---

Thank you for all the help, it is greatly appreciated! I wonder if adding a ledge will help solving it? Something similar to this:

[image: Ledge hiding plumbing]

This way, extensive cutting into plumbing/drywall/vent/vanity won't be necessary.

Comment: If you open up the wall, it may be that there are other options then the one you linked to. We can not really say what is best in the wall until we know how things are set up in the wall. If you are putting in vanity then it may be that  you can use the existing plumbing with some modifications. Whatever you do, you should put some 1/4 turn shutoff valves on the supply lines.

Comment: Thank you for taking a look and for the advice, @AlaskaMan. I will keep this thread up to date. Can't stop being surprised with all the shortcuts previous installers went through!

Comment: Unclear what you are so upset about with the existing plumbing.

Comment: Ha-ha, not the end of the world, just extra work. I've done multiple projects and every time I hope it's a "plug&play", there are always those small extras that result in triple time and budget. I guess it may be a lot worse in a 100 y.o. home...

Comment: This all looks straight forward unless you're installing a very uniquely designed sink and vanity. Based on your post once you get installed it shouldn't be difficult to modify what's already under the sink to work for you. If you run into a specific problem or have a question post it as a separate question.

Comment: Could you clarify how the existing drain conflicts with the new vanity?

Comment: Vanity has sink on the left, and the plumbing opens up on the right. So now I need to run about 36in of ABS pipes to make it work, but doesn't look like there is a straightforward solution due to complexities described above. I can't cut vanity either, as it has drawers on the right.

Comment: Due to the requirements of the drain plumbing on the right and the vanity sink on the left, it sounds like your only option is to open the wall up to see what you can do. You might, however, contact the location where you bought the vanity to see if they make a right sink/left drawer version and swap it out.